# Three seconds to take the 1st element of list?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, image, timing

I'm working with FashionMNIST, a small (70k) list of rules containing 28x28 images. I don't understand the slow-down in the example below. No matter the size of the list, simple operations like taking the first Part should never take 3 seconds:

```
fmnist = CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/12463dc0-26fb-4560-a586-7ab870421984"];
Length[fmnist]
RepeatedTiming[Extract[fmnist, {1}]]
RepeatedTiming @ RandomSample[fmnist, 2]
```

[image]

The FMNIST file is around 50mb, and `CloudPut` failed silently (which should be a bug). Anyhow, you can download fmnist in MX format [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x5v7l7pu2b0l8rw/fmnist.mx?dl=0) and in WDX format [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kpg0desajmpf5b/fmnist.wdx?dl=0).

Comment: Your `CloudGet` fails. Any other chance to share data?

Comment: @MarcoB Ok I added a dropbox link

Comment: @M.R. I think using mx format is not a good idea; it depends on Mma version and os. I cannot import it (well, I can but the result is `Null`). You could use wdx format (unfortunately at the cost of larger file size).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I added a link to the WDX export

Answer (score 2):

Something may be wrong on your end, I'm afraid. I can't reproduce the slow behavior:

```
Length[fmnist]
RepeatedTiming[Extract[fmnist, {1}]]
RepeatedTiming[RandomSample[fmnist, 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: I imported the WDX file from your Dropbox:

```
fmnist = Import["C:\\Users\\Marco\\Desktop\\fmnist.wdx"];
```

Comment: Same here; working with version 11.3 on macOS. But it takes rather long to load the wdx file into Mma @M.R., are you sure this `CloudObject` downloaded completely? Or is parts of the data loaded only when requested (and that without caching)?